# html5 audio/video playback produces error on chrome

Tags: html, jetty, html5-video

This implementation works fine for smaller videos but results in errors with larger videos and audio files. The application delivers 2 streams, audio/video to pop up chrome window based on the partial range requests received and attempts to sync both audio and video. With larger videos after around 7 minutes the audio will produce the following errors. This does not seem to occur with video only or audio only stream playbacks.

```
2018-03-22 12:57:03.096, FINER, I/O Error during playback with parameters , 
 HTTPresponse=HTTP/1.1 206 
 Date: Thu, 22 Mar 2018 10:55:01 GMT
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
 Content-Range: bytes 6913082-9044857/9044858
 Content-Length: 2131776
 Content-Type: audio/wav

, Content-Length=2131775}: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle 
timeout expired: 120001/120000 ms, 
2018-03-22 12:57:03.097, I/O Error during playback with parameters  
HTTPresponse=HTTP/1.1 206 
Date: Thu, 22 Mar 2018 10:55:01 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 6913082-9044857/9044858
Content-Length: 2131776
Content-Type: audio/wav

, Content-Length=2131775}: {1},
 java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: 
 Idle timeout expired: 120001/120000 ms
at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block
(SharedBlockingCallback.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:496)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Timeout ...

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 120001/120000 ms
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:219)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:220)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:496)
  at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
```

... means the browser didn't read from the stream for 120,001 ms (2 minutes) and the connection was closed.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So does this mean the jetty server closed the connection because of the timeout or is the issue with how chrome is handling the response? Can it handle both the audio and video as two separate requests?

Comment: would this be related - on the video request ERR:CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:16001618
Content-Range:bytes 0-16001617/16001618
Content-Type:video/webm     (Actual browser shows 5.1MB of the size). Audio request has net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Nothing magical here, its just a simple idle timeout.  Chrome had a active connection to Jetty, and didn't read anything, no bytes, nothing, nada, zilch for 120,001 ms and Jetty closed the connection due to its configured idle timeout.